# Adding a New Local Planner in Navigation

Tags: ros, plugin, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to add a [new local planner](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental/tree/hydro-devel/pose_follower) as a plugin to the navigation stack. I followed the guide [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) to do this and everything compiles fine, and the new plugin is available by `nav_core` (`rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core`), but when I am running the navigation, I get the error below:

```
[ INFO] [1417068766.032804515]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1417068766.131730337]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1417068766.473023497]: Resizing costmap to 4000 X 4000 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1417068766.593126231]: Received a 4000 X 4000 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1417068766.609460784]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1417068766.636893038]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1417068766.786537389]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1417068767.228129165]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1417068767.351801435]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1417068767.416552886]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/move_base/move_base: symbol lookup error: /home/yan/myrobot/shark/devel/lib//libpose_follower_lib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN18base_local_planner20TrajectoryPlannerROSC1Ev
[move_base-6] process has died [pid 2430, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/move_base/move_base odom:=shark/odom __name:=move_base __log:=/home/yan/.ros/log/f8e767fa-6909-11e4-9bd3-0024e832832e/move_base-6.log].
log file: /home/yan/.ros/log/f8e767fa-6909-11e4-9bd3-0024e832832e/move_base-6*.log
```

Running

```
 c++filt _ZN18base_local_planner20TrajectoryPlannerROSC1Ev
```

outputs

```
base_local_planner::TrajectoryPlannerROS::TrajectoryPlannerROS()
```

but the issue is `base_local_planner` exists in my CMakeLists.txt File

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pose_follower)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  base_local_planner 
  cmake_modules
  costmap_2d
  dynamic_reconfigure
  move_base
  move_base_msgs 
  actionlib 
  roscpp
  nav_core 
  tf 
  nav_msgs 
  pluginlib
)    

catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   LIBRARIES pose_follower
   CATKIN_DEPENDS base_local_planner cmake_modules costmap_2d  dynamic_reconfigure move_base move_base_msgs actionlib roscpp nav_core tf nav_msgs pluginlib
)    

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    
add_executable(pose_follower src/pose_follower.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pose_follower ${catkin_LIBRARIES} base_local_planner)

add_library(pose_follower_lib src/pose_follower.cpp)

add_dependencies(pose_follower nav_msgs_gencpp)

install(FILES blp_plugin.xml
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/pose_follower
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  PATTERN "*~" EXCLUDE
)

install(TARGETS pose_follower
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198419/adding-a-new-local-planner-in-navigation/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-27**:
I also checked [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/174486/about-undefined-symbol-error/) about this problem @Ken_in_JAPAN @fergs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @fergs, I added another `target_link_libraries` after `add_library` in my CMakeLists.txt, and it fixed the error:

```
add_library(pose_follower_lib src/pose_follower.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pose_follower_lib ${catkin_LIBRARIES} trajectory_planner_ros)
```

Although it seems pose_follower is [not compatible with navfn global planner](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/8238), and the robot is currently stuck.

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TrajectoryPlannerROS functions are found in the trajectory_planner_ros library, not base_local_planner.

However, I would expect that catkin_LIBRARIES would contain trajectory_planner_ros since you have base_local_planner package in the find_package().

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-27**:
I explicitly added  trajectory_planner_ros library to the `target_link_libraries()` (`target_link_libraries(pose_follower ${catkin_LIBRARIES} trajectory_planner_ros base_local_planner)`), but still getting the same error